# Traversing the elements of a bag list

Tags: traversal, jess, bag

I wanted to know if it would be possible to traverse through the elements of a bag list and store them into a variable?

Thank you very much
Ali

**Edited by laune using the code given by OP in some comment**

```
 (defglobal ?*Friends* = 0 ) 
 (bind ?*Friends* (bag create Bob))
 (bind ?*Friends* (bag create Nicolas))
 (bind ?*Friends* (bag create Nancy)) 
 (bind ?*Friends* (bag create John))
 (bind ?*Friends* (bag create George)))
```

now I want to go through this bag list and print any variable separately,

Comment: If you don't show any code you won't get any help. I do have an idea what a "bag" is, and I'm sure I know what a (Jess) list is, and I know how to traverse it. But since you'll have to have that "bag list" bound to a variable (or where else is it?), your question doesn't make sense. If it is in a slot, show the template - it could be a slot or a multislot or an ordered fact... As your Q stands now, I can only answer, "Yes, it is possible."

Comment: sorry for that, here is my code:


(defglobal ?*Friends* = 0 )
(bind ?*Friends* (bag create Bob))
(bind ?*Friends* (bag create Nicolas))
(bind ?*Friends* (bag create Nancy))
(bind ?*Friends* (bag create John))
(bind ?*Friends* (bag create George)))
now I want to go through this bag list and print any variable separately,(I mean not like what appears when using the (bag list ...). thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a bag in this way, and I don't think you need a bag, which is a set of key-value pairs. What you are doing is to create a simple list, one that contains Bob, trying to do  Nicolas, Nancy, John and George.

A bag would associate a key with a value, e.g.

```
(defglobal ?*Friends* = 0 )
(bind ?*Friends* (bag create my-friends))
(bag set ?*Friends* Bob "old and reliable")
%%...
(bag set ?*Friends* George "new and curious")
```

To get all the names of the friends you'd write

```
(bind ?names (bag props ?*Friends*))
```

which returns a list (Bob ... George).

But you could have created this list right away in the first place...

Comment: Well the problem is I don't want all of the items in the list to be printed at once, I want them to be printed one by one, not as a total list. will I have to do matching for each and every single slot value?

Comment: First it was "store [bag list elements] into a variable", now it is "to be printed one by one". Are you sure that you know what you want/need to program?

Comment: Well that is why I wanted to traverse through the list, to be able to do all these steps later on, but with what you have provided, I will just have a list of elements which I cant traverse, Have I the point?

Comment: The word "cant" baffles me. You *can* traverse a list of elements.